# Dart sqflite clear db and insert

Tags: flutter, dart, sqflite

I'm having trouble doing a very simple task, delete a DB or drop table and insert new values. Tried several things but I always end up with an error `SqfliteDatabaseException (DatabaseException(database_closed 1))`. This happens when `batchInsert` is called. I'd expect the new db connection to be opened after `openDatabase` after deleting the old one.

This is my latest code:

`sqlite_service.dart`

```
class SQLiteService {
  static final SQLiteService instance = SQLiteService.init();
  static Database? _database;
  SQLiteService.init();

  static const String dbName = 'bookies_list.db';
  static const String tableName = 'bookies';

  Future<Database> get database async {
    if (_database != null) return _database!;
    _database = await _initDB();
    return _database!;
  }

  Future<Database> _initDB() async {
    Directory documentsDirectory = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
    String path = join(documentsDirectory.path, dbName);
    return await openDatabase(path, version: 1, onCreate: _onCreate);
  }

  Future _onCreate(Database db, int version) async {
    await db.execute(
        'CREATE TABLE bookies (${BookieFields.id} INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, ${BookieFields.name} TEXT NOT NULL)');
  }

  //* Methods *//

  static Future<void> batchInsert(Set bookieSet) async {
    final db = await instance.database;
    Batch batch = db.batch();
    for (var bookie in bookieSet) {
      print('name: $bookie');
      batch.insert(tableName, {'name': bookie});
    }
    List<Object?> result = await batch.commit(noResult: true);
    print('result is $result');
  }

  static Future<List<Bookie>> getAllBookies() async {
    final db = await instance.database;
    const orderBy = '${BookieFields.name} ASC';
    final result = await db.query(tableName, orderBy: orderBy);
    return result.map((json) => Bookie.fromJson(json)).toList();
  }

  static Future<int> getDBVersion() async {
    final db = await instance.database;
    final localVersion = await db.getVersion();
    return localVersion;
  }

  static Future<void> deleteSQLiteDB() async {
    Directory documentsDirectory = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
    String path = join(documentsDirectory.path, dbName);
    final db = await instance.database;
    await deleteDatabase(path);
    //await db.delete(tableName);
    // // Future _onCreate(Database db, int version) async {
    // //   await db.execute(
    // //       'CREATE TABLE bookies (${BookieFields.id} INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, ${BookieFields.name} TEXT NOT NULL)');
    // //   await db
    // //       .execute('CREATE TABLE localVersion (version INTEGER PRIMARY KEY )');
    // // }

     await openDatabase(path, version:1 , onCreate:_onCreate);
  }

  static Future<void> setNewLocalVersion(int newVersion) async {
    final db = await instance.database;
    await db.setVersion(newVersion);
  }
}
```

`some_other_file.dart`

```
  Future<void> _updateBookieList() async {
    final bool updateBookies = await isBookieUpdateNeeded();
    if (updateBookies) {
      print(' update');
      await SQLiteService.deleteSQLiteDB();
      final Set<String>? newBookieSet = await FirebaseRTDB().getBookiesUpdate();
      if (newBookieSet != null && newBookieSet.isNotEmpty) {
        await SQLiteService.batchInsert(newBookieSet);
        var foo = await SQLiteService.getAllBookies();
        print('bookie list: $foo');
        final int remoteVersion = await FirebaseRTDB().getRemoteVersion();
        SQLiteService.setNewLocalVersion(remoteVersion);
      } else {
        print('update failed');
      }
    } else {
      print('no update');
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `database` getter returns `_database` if it is not null.  When you delete the database in `deleteSQliteDB` you should therefore add `_database = null`. This ensures that the next call to the `database` getter will open the database. It also makes the statement `await openDatabase(path, version:1 , onCreate:_onCreate)` in the `deleteSQLiteDB` method redundant: it's better to force the opening of the database via the same code, so that you would only ever have to change the code in one place if, for instance, you bump the version number.